# Securing a RESTful API with SSL?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku

I am looking for a way to have my iOS app securely communicate with a RESTful API I am building in Ruby on Rails.

If I follow Heroku's "[SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)" document, and allow my Rails app to be accessed via HTTPS, if I make HTTPS calls from my iOS app (via `NSMutableURLRequest()`) will it be secured? Or will people still be able to decipher the parameters?

If this is not a good choice, what are some suggestions?

Comment: Secure against what exactly? Secure for the end user on a private network? For them on a public network? Against a hacker with access to your app?

Comment: @Wain something like protecting passwords and emails from login being sniffed out of the network.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using SSL will secure all data being transmitted to/from the API, in case someone is sniffing or capturing your network traffic.

Just make sure your requests are going to https. Once you've enabled SSL if your server is not properly configured clients may still be able to post to http without SSL security. So I'd advice to ensure your apps are set to use an https url.

Answer (score 2):

To secure for the end user on a private network you could take MITM attacks out of scope and just use HTTPS.

For users on a public network MITM is a reality and you need to check the certificate from the server to make sure it's really the certificate from your server. You should be checking the domain name and also the certificate (or a hash of the certificate).

Against a hacker with access to your app (which can be downloaded by anyone from the store), is very expensive and involves a lot of checksummed checkpointing, and even then it's only hard for the attacker, not impossible.

Comment: If I'm only making requests to my server and not accepting any requests is it necessary to check the certificate? Because I am hardcoding the URL into the app it shouldn't be going anywhere else right?

Comment: That doesn't stop someone from intercepting the request, stealing the details and then forwarding the request. To prevent that the app has to verify the identity of the server certificate and not make the request if it's invalid.

Comment: how do the modify it if its encrypted?

Comment: It's encrypted between the sender and receiver, the MITM acts as the receiver so it can decrypt the content and then encrypt it again to send to the real server.

Comment: wouldn't the man in the middle need to know the key to decrypt it?

Comment: He has the key. ssl is a negotiated encryption, the problem is you didn't check and negotiated with the wrong receiver...

Comment: I see. This might be an entirely different question, but how would I go about performing this check?

Comment: Take a look at the AFNetworking code related to SSL pinning (the URL connection delegate methods or URL session auth handling)

Comment: If you use a hash of the certificate there will be a problem when the certificate expires and a new one is put in service at the server.

Comment: @Zaph that's generally an issue when pinning to the certificate as the app needs some way to verify it, so you will generally need to plan for cert changes and make specific releases, often hand in hand with forced updates to the users and / or a fallback validation of the root certificate - it's a complicated business...

Answer (score 2):

Using ssl, and checking the certificate provided by the server will prevent MITM attacks. This doesn't mean you are preventing users from faking request to your APIs.

This means one can simply reverse engineer your client application, and build a clone application making valid requests to your server.
This is very unlike to happen if you are running a small service but it could, so always validate your inputs on the server side and treat them as untrusted, as you can not say where they are coming from.

Comment: I am only really worried about requests going to the server, as data coming from it isn't very sensitive.

Comment: What are your concerns? Do users need to be registered? Is it an high profile project? Why is it important that the data comes directly from your application?

Answer (score 1):

By reverse engineering your code other people will always be able to decipher the parameters. You can make it harder, but not impossible. HTTPS only secures the network connection, not your code. From the encrypted network traffic it is not possible to discover the parameter names or values.

Comment: by `reverse engineering` do you mean somehow reading my compiled code?

Comment: Unless an attacker performs a MITM attack

Comment: Yes, reading you compiled code. Compiled code can be disassembled and read as assembly language.

Comment: If the remote host's SSL/TLS certificate is validated MITM attach shouldn't be possible.